# retrieve data put into non-directory file by using -mv command

Tags: command-line, find

I used the command below to move my data to a directory:

```
find . -name '*.mat' -exec mv {} ./ooutputs \;
```

However the directory of `./ooutputs` does not exist. A file named `ootputs` is then created which I cannot open.

Is there anyway to retrieve the data inside the file?

Many thanks.

Wenxu

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when the target for the `mv` command is not an existing directory, it renames the source file as the target; when used within a `find` command, that means each successive file that matches the predicate will overwrite the previous one. So in your case, the `./ooutputs` file will now contain only the contents of the last `.mat` file that was matched. To avoid accidents like this it's good practice to always include a trailing slash character when you are moving files to a new directory i.e.

```
find . -name '*.mat' -exec mv {} ./ooutputs/ \;
```

since this will throw an error if `/ooutputs` is not in fact an existing directory. I don't know of a way to recover the other files except from backups - sorry.